# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings returns null for a simple console app

Tags: c#, appsettings

I've checked all obvious pitfalls and this is weird

**Program.cs**

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var set1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Setting1"];
            //set1 is null
        }
```

and 
**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
...
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Setting1" value="May 5, 2014"/>
  </appSettings>
...
```

I have other projects that work fine. Why would it stop working suddenly?

Comment: Clean>Rebuilt if wouldn't work, close visual studio and it's add-in/on etc. Reopen>clean>built again. Your code looks good

Answer (score -1):

Cleaning project and deleting bin and obj folders resolved it